# Fullscreen Libgdx HTML5 not working on mobile

Tags: gwt, libgdx

My function to toggle fullscreen:

```
public void toggleFullScreen() {

        if(!Gdx.graphics.isFullscreen())
            Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode());
        else
            Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(App.WIDTH, App.HEIGHT);

    }
```

Works on desktop but not on mobile, why?

Comment: Apps are inherently full screen, what are you asking?

Comment: Its in an iframe in browser. With the code above I can make the canvas go fullscreen on desktop browsers. I am wondering why it does not work that simply on mobile browsers.

Comment: Mobile browsers do not allow full screen page viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not work because the functionality is not supported by libgdx' HTML backend. Could be changed, you should open an issue or PR.

EDIT: After checking the backend source code, I must change my statement on SO. The code is in the backend since 2015 and is working for me on all systems except iOS.

Comment: Thank you I opened an issue https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5621

Answer (score 1):

I ended up calling a JavaScript function from LibGDX with [JsInterop](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html).

JavaScript

```
 function toggleFullscreen() {    
        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        canvas.requestFullscreen();
    }
```

Java

```
  @JsMethod(namespace = GLOBAL)
public static native void toggleFullscreen();
```

Does not work with iOS though as Safari does not support Fullscreen API. I will just set Canvas width and height to Viewport width and height for iOS.

Comment: Please add this to your issue, or do you think you could make a PR?

Comment: @MrStahlfelge As soon as I have a usable solution for iOS

Comment: For iOS, there is none